# Format a text in the textbox

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format a selected text to bold inside a textbox but not happening. However, it is hapenning in a span/div. My code

```
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Untitled Document</title> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function FormatSelectedWord(txtBox,style) 
{ 

var selectedText = document.selection 
? document.selection.createRange().text 
: txtBox.value.substring(txtBox.selectionStart,txtBox.selectionEnd); 

if(selectedText!='') 
{ 
var newText='<'+style+'>'+selectedText+'</'+style+'>'; 
txtBox.value=txtBox.value.replace(selectedText,newText) 
spOutput.innerHTML=txtBox.value; 
} 
} 
</script> 
</head> 
<body> 


<input type="text" name="txtBox"> </input> 
<input type="button" value="Bold" onclick="FormatSelectedWord(txtBox,'b')"> 
<span id="spOutput"></span> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Is it possible to do it insde a textbox. If so how?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible to style the text in a text box. You can make your div or span contentEditable=true if you need formatted text that is editable.

Comment: How did I never know about this?!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than re-invent the wheel, you're better off looking at implementing [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) or some other, similar thing that does this - it's quite easy. It's very commonly sought after functionality, and it's called a "Rich text editor", for if you want to go Googling :)

Trying to add this kind of functionality yourself is a *huge* can of worms, and you really don't want to get involved :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of what I think you want: **http://jsfiddle.net/6gQJC/1/**

and here's what you asked: http://jsfiddle.net/6gQJC/

```
txtBox is undefined
```

So this:

```
<input type="text" name="txtBox"> </input>
```

needs to be

```
<input type="text" id="txtBox" name="txtBox"> </input>
```

and then

```
function FormatSelectedWord(txtBox,style) 
{ 
     var textbox = document.getElementById('textBox');
```